# Using the Python API is there anyway to get the Test Run's Status?

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I currently have a python program which exports Test Runs, Test Plans, and Test Cases to CSV.

I am using the [TestRun Model](https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/tcms.testruns.models.html#tcms.testruns.models.TestRun) but I cannot get the information highlighted in the status column seen [here](https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/testrun.html). Is there anyway to get this information?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I currently have a python program which exports Test Runs, Test Plans, and Test Cases to CSV.

This is great. Please consider contributing your script under https://github.com/kiwitcms/api-scripts

> I am using the TestRun Model but I cannot get the information highlighted in the status column seen here. Is there anyway to get this information?

Note: these screenshots are old!

There is no TestRun.status field, the status is only a visual property which is calculated by the UI based on the presence or absence of TestRun.stop_date field. If this field is null/None then the status is "Running", otherwise it is "Stopped".

In the current TR search page for example we query the `TestRun.filter` API with a 
`stop_date__isnull=True` parameter.

Comment: Thanks! I am already exporting the stop_date field from the TestRun model. Ill run this by our documentation folks and let them know to check that field. Unfortunately this script was developed on contract so I cannot share it externally. Appreciate the help though!

Comment: Ask your customer if you can open source. Maybe they wouldn't mind. They will retain copyright and all.